# Using function JHtml::date() in joomla 3.5

Tags: php, function, joomla

I'm going to help this function(`JHtml::date();`) convertion *Gregorian* date *Jalali* date.
But when I use this code error page is displayed:

> DateTime::__construct():

[image: Screenshot of the error page]

My code is:

```
echo JHtml::date ($input = '28th May، 2016 11:29PM', 'jS M، Y g:iA', false );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug n joomla as I dont know why it depends on the correct path of tmp and log folder if date is used. So first you check if your log and tmp path defined in Joomla under global configuration are correct.

Also check the folder permissions. It should be 755 for folders and 644 for files except configuration.php file.

Comment: Thank You.but im working in localhost.and this code problem is only one file.In other places used properly. I think my code has a problem. Because when I use the following code, the code working correctly `code` echo JHtml::date ($input = 'now', 'jS M، Y g:iA', false ); `code`